# Custom options menu for every fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

i have a problem.
I am trying to change the default option menu, different for every fragment.
I created an xml file for every fragment and i putted them inside res/menu folder.
Now i don't know how to tell android to change the default options menu in every fragment.
I putted the fragment inside a pager view.
The menu i am talking about is the one on the bottom near the home and back buttons.

this is one of the custom menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.prova.Frase"  >  

 <item  
        android:id="@+id/one"  
        android:title="Scatta Foto"/>  

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/two"  
        android:title="Scegli dal Rullino"/>  

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/three"  
        android:title="Prossimo sfondo predefinito"/>  

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on every fragment you have to override `onCreateOptionsMenu`.   Don't forget to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` (in `onCreate` e.g.). [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater)) you can find `onCreateOptionsMenu`'s documentation

Comment: Didn't know was so simple.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can override the onCreateOptionsMenu in each of the Fragments. Hope this helps

```
@Override 
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragMenu, menu);
   this.menu = menu;
}
```

Comment: From the earlier post comment, can i assume its working now. If not let me know.

Comment: Yes yes it's working, I did with blackbelt answer but propably yours would work too

Comment: Glad you found the solution here