# How to change Menu Item icon from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I access my Menu from my fragment and then change the icon of one of the menu items there?

What I am doing is querying my local DB to see if a certain entry exists when the fragment is shown. If it does display a solid icon, if not, display an outlined icon.

Comment: like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440133/custom-options-menu-for-every-fragment)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your fragments `onCreate()` method you can use `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` to allow your fragment to handle different menu items than it's root `Activity`.
So you could do something like this in your fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

And then, you can override any of the menu life-cycle methods in your fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment, menu);
    // You can look up you menu item here and store it in a global variable by 
    // 'mMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.my_menu_item);'
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_to_change_icon_for); // You can change the state of the menu item here if you call getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); somewhere in your code
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    // Handle actions based on the id field.
}
```

Comment: The critical part was calling `getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();` anywhere in my code to refresh the menu. It works great.

Answer (score 2):

I found a simpler way of doing it than in the provided answer:

```
Toolbar toolbar = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
Menu menu = toolbar.getMenu();
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.item_settings);
item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_settings);
```

Access the menu from the toolbar.